# intercepting feed:// in safari5

Tags: rss, feed, safari-extension

I am writing an extension for Safari5 and I am trying to intercept the fact that the user is clicking on an RSS icon and loading a feed://.... URL to offer him/her subscription options. I have tried to register a start content script for the feed://*/* whitelist pattern but that does not work. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only apply extensions to the http(s?) protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I've done exactly this in my ["Add to Google Reader"](http://codaset.com/robwilkerson/add-to-google-reader/wiki) extension. Feel free to take a look at the source code to see what I did. I tried variations of white- and blacklists, but ended up having to check manually.